# Getting total sum on column GridView from xtragrid with conditional if Y = z

Tags: c#, sum, devexpress, xtragrid

I want to sum data on column X from xtragrid were column Y = 'z'.
I have input few item on xtragrid and I want to put that sum result on TextBox.

I've got this clue from other stack question

> myList.Where(x => x.RecType == 1).Sum(x => x.Income)

but i'm stuck there when try to put it on my code for gridview. 
This code i try so far:

```
private void findTotalFood()
        {
            decimal sum = 0;
            for (Int32 x = 0; x < gridView1.DataRowCount; x++)
            {
                DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(x);
                sum += gridView1.Where(a => a.row["IDITEMTYPE"] == 1).Select(a => a.row["TOTAL"]).Sum();
            }
        }
```

and i have error on that line:

> DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is it the problem because I can't use that sum method on xtragrid, or I using wrong method? If so, what should I use for getting result that i want?

Comment: If your code has an error, dont you think that is important to share with us?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I guess it's not error like I can run it but failed to process, but more like wrong type of command line there. So I can't even run it. Error said this `DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` ps. I'm so sorry that I forgot to tag about devexpress